# Set secure flag to ingress nginx affinity cookie / edit set-cookie header by nginx rule

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

**My Problem**

I'm using an nginx ingress controller which sets an [affinity cookie](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#cookie-affinity).
It sets automatically the *secure* flag to the cookie when called by https.

But in my case all requests are sent by a proxy via http to the nginx ingress.
Because nthe ginx ingress thinks it's only http, the secure flag is not set.

**Solution?**

I think there are no [option](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#cookie-affinity) to force the *secure* flag.

But there is an option to [add additional nginx directives](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet). I also found a request [how to set the secure flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2880). But the solution just adds new headers. I can't added the existing cookie header by this method.

So my question is: Is there a way to edit the cookie header via the nginx ingress rules and set the *secure* flag?