# Adding Secure cookie to one particular value in nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx-ingress

I am trying to add secure cookie. Following is the configuration.

```
  ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: nginx-external
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "test-name"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: "Lax"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
  healthCheckUrl: /health/check
```

I am unable to figure out how to add it.

I have tried using these threads/methods, but it did not help me -

1. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2880
2. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6812
3. [Set secure flag to ingress nginx affinity cookie / edit set-cookie header by nginx rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508820/set-secure-flag-to-ingress-nginx-affinity-cookie-edit-set-cookie-header-by-ngi).